# What kind of screwdriver can unscrew this?

Tags: screws

I have never seen a screw head like the one attached.  My local hardware store directed me to get different T heads (T6, T8, T10, T15, T20, T25) and try them until I find a match.  None of them work though because as you can see from the picture, in the middle of the star there is a raised seed that prevents the driver from entering the head and engaging the star edges.

What can I use to unscrew this??
[image]

Comment: https://www.harborfreight.com/33-pc-security-bit-set-68459.html

Comment: It's a so called security torx head.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like a "Tamper-Resistant Torx" screw, according to http://resources.tannerbolt.com/articles/what-type-of-screw-is-this/ .  Another name is "Torx Security" screws.  I get some good results on Amazon for Tamper Proof screws too.

Test what size was closest (diagonal fit) to get the approximate size you need.  Probably the best action is to buy a whole set of interchangeable heads for your screwdriver.

Comment: You are correct, I have a set of those bits.

Comment: I have a set too. They were less then $7 on special from my local hardware megastore. That said, depending on the size and tightness I have defeated these screws with a standard small flathead screwdriver wedged between spokes 1 and 3 (or 2 and for or whatever)

Comment: Otherwise some careful work with a drill or dremel to remove the centre knob and regular torx?

Comment: Usually the center pin is so weak anyways that poking into the screw with a pointy object like a small flathead screw driver will break it off and allow using a regular torx bit afterwards.

Comment: @WooShell Keep in mind that this process is irreversible, so it definitely leads behind evidence of tampering, in case this may be relevant further down the line.

Comment: Alternatively you can drill a hole in the center of your standard torx heads to make them compatible with these tamper-resistant monstrosities.

Comment: @R.. that may be a last resort, but you're more likely to break your drill bit and the torx driver, and now need to replace all three.

Comment: If you happen to have some of the Ring doorbells, they include a screwdriver that will possibly fit this. My Ring Stick-Up cam has a screwdriver that has this pattern.

Comment: @LucasF.: If the screw is installed on one of the OP's own possessions, who cares if they detach the central pin?

Comment: Instead of drilling a torx head, wouldn't it work if you take a cheap throwaway flat-head screwdriver and make a small cut in the middle with a file or a hacksaw?

Comment: @Headcrab Yes, although this usually damages the screw and it may be harder to loosen the screw.

Comment: Can someone explain how it's "tamper resistant" when it's just as easy to get a suitable TR Torx head screwdriver from my local hardware store as a normal Philips driver?

Comment: @Dai - It used to be that TR Torx couldn't be bought at your neighbourhood hardware store; they were a specialty item. The first time I remember seeing them was on a cable tv box (1980's?). I couldn't find a source for an over-the-counter bit set and ended up making my own. Now that they are more universally available, I guess no one thought to change the name.

Comment: @Sean It may be relevant for warranty. "We can tell you tampered with this. Your warranty is thus void."